# The way turning a matrix of a operator to be an upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw ways of turning a matrix to be a diagonalized matrix or turning it to be Jordan form, but I haven't found there is a way to put a matrix to be an upper triangular form.

Suppose the vector space $V$ is on field $\mathbb C$ and the basis of the $V$ is $\beta_0$ and there is an operator $T$. I don't clearly know how to turn this matrix to be an upper triangular matrix even though on the complex field it is guaranteed that this is possible.

Originally, my thought is to use Gaussian elimination, but I now feel this is not a proper way since GE only changes the basis of the codomain, but since the matrix for an operator, the change of basis of codomain will also affect the basis of the domain. As a result, if I get an upper triangular matrix just by GE, then the matrix will be $_{\beta}T_{\beta_0}$ that is not correct.

Then now my idea is that when trying to turn a matrix of an operator to be a diagonal matrix, first find the eigenvector basis and use the change basis matrix. As a result, it will look like $P\Lambda P^{-1}=A$ in which $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix and A is just a normal operator matrix.

Thus I want to ask that is that possible to turn a matrix to be an upper triangular matrix by finding a proper basis? Or Is there another way of doing this?

Or actually, Jordan form is just the way of finding upper triangular form for operator matrices that don't have a basis made of eigenvectors?

Comment: Look for "Schur decomposition"

Comment: Jordan form is indeed an example of an upper triangular form